# How to write scope for not contain or null or empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

I wondering how to correctly write scope which in sql looks like:

```
Caterer.where('robots NOT LIKE :noindex OR robots IS NULL OR robots IS ?', smr: "%noindex%", "").where(active: true)
```

Right now it looks really ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scope :noindex_robots, -> { where('robots NOT LIKE :noindex OR robots IS NULL OR robots IS ?', smr: "%noindex%", "") }
scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
```

And use it like this: `Caterer.active.noindex_robots`

If you describe the logic behind noindex_robots, I can try to refactor it as well.

Comment: I want to select 'Caterer' where robots attribute doesn't contain noindex(because sometimes it can be stored like: noindex,nofollow or index,nofollow or index,follow) or is nil or empty.